# Conditional Group By Statement

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the data frame :

```
  PRODUCT  SPEED  HEIGHT  LENGTH      DATE
      30       10    5       8         2019-08
      30       13    9       15        2019-08
      31       19    8       12        2019-08
      30       5     6       3         2019-08
      31       11    8       6         2019-09
      30       11    8       6         2019-09
      30       11    8       6         2019-09
      31       11    8       6         2019-09
      31       11    8       6         2019-09
```

I want to produce a table that has the averages for SPEED, HEIGHT, LENGTH by month. I also want to have a column in that table that has the percentage of the total PRODUCT per month when PRODUCT=30.

My desired output:

```
  DATE      SPEED   HEIGHT   LENGTH   PRODUCT
  2019-08    11.75    7        9.5      75%
  2019-09     11      8         6       40%
```

I have the following code:

```
avg_summary = df.groupby(['DATE']).agg({'SPEED': 'mean',
                                         'HEIGHT' : 'mean',
                                         'LENGTH': 'mean',
                                         'PRODUCT': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

This outputs:

```
  DATE      SPEED   HEIGHT   LENGTH   PRODUCT
  2019-08    11.75    7        9.5      4
  2019-09     11      8         6       5
```

I know I can do `(df[df.PRODUCT == 30].shape[0])`to find the count in the whole data frame for when PRODUCT == 30, but I cannot figure out how to count the number of instances for when PRODUCT=30 by month.

I figured I could divide the number of instances for when PRODUCT=30 by the total count of PRODUCT to get the result I am looking for.

Any help/tips would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close, after your groupby, filter your data on `PRODUCT == 30`, groupby on date again and then divide the size product by the original `avg_summary`:

```
s = df.query('PRODUCT==30').groupby('DATE')['PRODUCT'].size().to_numpy()
avg_summary['PRODUCT'] = s / avg_summary['PRODUCT'] * 100
```

**output**

```
      DATE  SPEED  HEIGHT  LENGTH  PRODUCT
0  2019-08  11.75       7     9.5     75.0
1  2019-09  11.00       8     6.0     40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two things that you were talking about and I think that this will get you what you want.

```
counts = df[df['PRODUCT']==30].groupby(['DATE']).agg({'PRODUCT': 'count'}).reset_index()

avg_summary['PRODUCT'] = (counts['PRODUCT'] / avg_summary['PRODUCT'])*100
```

First off you filter on the PRODUCT=30 and then you group by DATE, which gives you the counts by month of PRODUCT=30.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write an inline function to pass in for the product column.  An f-string can be used if you want the % sign in the column:

```
df = (df.groupby('DATE', as_index=False)
        .agg({'SPEED': 'mean',
              'HEIGHT': 'mean',
              'LENGTH': 'mean',
              'PRODUCT': lambda x: f'{100*(x.eq(30).sum()/len(x)):.0f}%'})
      )


print(df)

      DATE  SPEED  HEIGHT  LENGTH PRODUCT
0  2019-08  11.75       7     9.5     75%
1  2019-09  11.00       8     6.0     40%
```